# Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException: A connection string is configured but Umbraco could not connect to the database

Tags: c#, azure, umbraco

Hello guys anyone with Umbraco experience and Azure, I hosted my website of umbraco on azure and it first worked well, however now am getting this error, I have read almost all posts about this but I couldn't get the solution, actually when I run the project locally it works and connects well to the Azure SQL server and database , but after hosting it throws an exception below am using version 8.1.2:

```
[BootFailedException: Boot failed: Umbraco cannot run. See Umbraco's log file for more details.

-> Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException: A connection string is configured but Umbraco could not connect to the database.
   at Umbraco.Core.RuntimeState.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, ILogger logger)
   at Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, IProfilingLogger profilingLogger)
   at Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.Boot(IRegister register, DisposableTimer timer)]
   Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException.Rethrow(BootFailedException bootFailedException) +226
   Umbraco.Web.Composing.ModuleInjector`1.Init(HttpApplication context) +162
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +523
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +220
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Boot failed: Umbraco cannot run. See Umbraco's log file for more details.

-> Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException: A connection string is configured but Umbraco could not connect to the database.
   at Umbraco.Core.RuntimeState.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, ILogger logger)
   at Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory, IProfilingLogger profilingLogger)
   at Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.Boot(IRegister register, DisposableTimer timer)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +658
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check that you have given access to your hosting server to the database firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Azure App Service for Umbraco, in the Azure portal, make sure that your database firewall settings has the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" set to Yes.